# Puttting a list next to an image

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and I'm designing my first web page with pics and navigation bars, so I'm trying to follow my wireframe design and I'm kind of confused because I want to put the 'sign in and log in' buttons next to the logo/favicon, I only could do it with the text, as you can see I used a list because is what I'm learning now  **I'm not using java script  and buttons yet**

So I just wanted to know if it's possible or there are other ways to organize it
I hope you can help me :)

1. here is the html code

```css
#top-bar {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
}


.nav-bar   {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom:4px solid #000000;
    
}

.nav-bar ul   {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav-bar li    {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline;
  
}
.nav-bar li a{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:4em 4em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
}

.header, img.img-fluid{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 27em;
    margin-right: 27em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 220px; 
}

.header, h2.text{
    margin-top: 55px;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight :bolder;
}
.headerh2{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.ini-reg, li{
    color: #6E6E6E;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
}

.cont{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.item{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.ini-reg ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline;
}


.topnav,a.active{
    background-color: #6E6E6E
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title> Bo(ok) Spectator </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sies="96x96" href="img/favicon def.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icofont/icofont.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div id="top-bar"></div>
            <div class="nav-bar">
                <nav id="nav-cont" class="cf">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Géneros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Aportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Preguntas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="text float-left">Bo(ok) Spectator</h2>
                    <img src="img/favicon def.png" class="img-fluid">
                    <nav class="ini-reg">
                        <ul class="cont">
                            <li><a href="#regi"  target="_blank" class="item" id="tag">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#inises" target="_blank" class="item">Registrarse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

3. and a pic of what is the result

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69QJg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with without using the `nav` class for the `ul` just use `ul` below the image and add `display:flex` to `ul`

```
  <div class="container">
            <div>
                <h2 class="text float-left">Bo(ok) Spectator</h2>
                <img src="img/favicon def.png" class="img-fluid">
                    <ul class="cont">
                        <li><a href="#regi"  target="_blank" class="item" id="tag">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#inises" target="_blank" class="item">Registrarse</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```